# Convert an 8-bit character string to a sequence of 16-word blocks

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I'm trying converse PHP and Javascript page to C# with password hashing system (password hashing with chap token). So I have example page to show steps result:

```
<?php
   $chapid='\115';
   $chapchallenge= '\274\013\242\243\236\226\151\224\070\023\243\207\252\061\016\254';
   $pass = '123456';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    alert('<?php echo $chapid; ?>' + '<?php echo $pass; ?>' + '<?php echo $chapchallenge; ?>');
    alert(((str2binl('<?php echo $chapid; ?>' + '<?php echo $pass; ?>' + '<?php echo $chapchallenge; ?>'))));
    alert((coreMD5(str2binl('<?php echo $chapid; ?>' + '<?php echo $pass; ?>' + '<?php echo $chapchallenge; ?>'))));
    alert(binl2hex(coreMD5(str2binl('<?php echo $chapid; ?>' + '<?php echo $pass; ?>' + '<?php echo $chapchallenge; ?>'))));
//-->
</script>

/*
 * Convert an 8-bit character string to a sequence of 16-word blocks, stored
 * as an array, and append appropriate padding for MD4/5 calculation.
 * If any of the characters are >255, the high byte is silently ignored.
 */
function str2binl(str)
{
  var nblk = ((str.length + 8) >> 6) + 1 // number of 16-word blocks
  var blks = new Array(nblk * 16)
  for(var i = 0; i < nblk * 16; i++) blks[i] = 0
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    blks[i>>2] |= (str.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF) << ((i%4) * 8)
  blks[i>>2] |= 0x80 << ((i%4) * 8)
  blks[nblk*16-2] = str.length * 8
  return blks
}
```

First alert displays string "M123456¼¢£i8£ª1¬", so in my code I converted input using:

```
public static string AsciiOctalToString(string ascii)
{
    var list = ascii.Split('\\');
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string octalPart in list.Where(x => x.Length > 0))
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(octalPart, 8);
        builder.Append(Convert.ToChar(i));
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Next I have to convert this string to bytes (like `str2binl(str)`) but it is in some strange format. I don't understand how to 'Convert an 8-bit character string to a sequence of 16-word blocks'. Expected result (from alert 2) is `{858927437, -1137298124, -1633443317, 949250454, -1433951469, -2136207823, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,184,0}`. I translated `str2binl(str)` to:

```
public static int[] Str2Binl(string str)
{
    var nblk = ((str.Length + 8) >> 6) + 1; // number of 16-word blocks
    var blks = new int[nblk*16];

    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        blks[i >> 2] |= (str[i] & 0xFF) << (i%4*8);
        blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << (i%4*8);
    }
    blks[nblk*16 - 2] = str.Length*8;
    return blks;
}
```

but my result is different than expected.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong with this?

I added brackets for JavaScript code:

```
function str2binl(str)
{
  var nblk = ((str.length + 8) >> 6) + 1 // number of 16-word blocks
  var blks = new Array(nblk * 16)
  for(var i = 0; i < nblk * 16; i++) 
  {
    blks[i] = 0
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
  {
    blks[i>>2] |= (str.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF) << ((i%4) * 8)
  }
  blks[i>>2] |= 0x80 << ((i%4) * 8)
  blks[nblk*16-2] = str.length * 8
  return blks
}
```

but line `blks[i>>2] |= 0x80 << ((i%4) * 8)` needs iterator too so how it's work in JS?

P.S. I can't use this JS library in my code, I need only hashed password (it's not a web app).

Comment: If you are really concerned about security, you shouldn't do your own hashing, nor even use MD5 or SHA, but one derived from PBKDF2. Do you really need to keep your current algorithm?

Comment: .NET strings are not byte arrays; They are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. Perhaps you stick to using a byte array.

Comment: You have two `for` loops in javascript, they execute one command each. You have one `for` loop in C#, executing two commands.

Comment: The first one initializes the array to 0, C# that's already by default. But you are right about the second part: in JS, the line with `0x80` is outside the array and in C# it's inside.

Comment: The orignal code has one instruction in the for loop while you code has two.  The 2nd statement in your for loop only get executed once in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that you placed two lines inside the `for` loop instead of only one. Does this work?

```
public static int[] Str2Binl(string str)
{
    var nblk = ((str.Length + 8) >> 6) + 1; // number of 16-word blocks
    var blks = new int[nblk*16];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        blks[i >> 2] |= (str[i] & 0xFF) << (i%4*8);
    }

    blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << (i%4*8);
    blks[nblk*16 - 2] = str.Length*8;
    return blks;
}
```

Anyway, as I already commented, If you are really concerned about security, you shouldn't do your own hashing, nor even use MD5 or SHA, but one derived from PBKDF2. Unless if for some reason you need to keep your current algorithm.

On the other hand, your `AsciiOctalToString` gives me a different string: `¼♂¢£??i?8‼£?ª1♫¬`.

BTW, you can avoid using that `where` with this (although you may like it less):

```
var list = ascii.Split(new char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Thanks for infomation about split, it's better solution :)

You're right about loops. But what is iterator in last line:
     `blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << (i%4*8);`

Need declaration 'i', so it must be part of some loop.

Comment: Your output from 'AsciiOctalToString' is different because you put only '$chapchallenge'. I have '$"{AsciiOctalToString(chapid)}{pass}{AsciiOctalToString(chapchallenge)}";

Comment: Oops, you are right, I fixed that `i` variable. In JavaScript the variable stays alive after the `for` but in C# it doesn't, so you have to declare it outside the loop.